# Can a set have lists as its elements?

Tags: python, logic

I am trying to get unique lists which can consist duplicate values,can I use sets to get unique lists?

To be more specific ,here is an example:

```
my_list=[[1,2,1],[1,2,2],[1,2,2],[1,1,2],[2,2,2]]
```

what i would want is :

```
set_list=[[1,2,1],[1,2,2],[1,1,2],[2,2,2]]
```

is this possible?
Thanks in advance for your kind response :)

Comment: No, lists are not hashable...

Comment: Then what can I use to perform this?

Comment: You can use tuples instead of lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, a **`list` is not hashable**. You will get the following error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Given **the list only contains hashable objects**, you can however convert the list to a `tuple` and add the tuples. So you could do something like:

```
>>> my_list=[[1,2,1],[1,2,2],[1,2,2],[1,1,2],[2,2,2]]
>>> set_tuples = {tuple(a_list) for a_list in my_list}
>>> set_tuples
{(1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2), (1, 1, 2)}
```

You can then for instance construct a uniqueness filter with:

```
my_list=[[1,2,1],[1,2,2],[1,2,2],[1,1,2],[2,2,2]]
result = []
unique_set = set()
for sublist in my_list:
    the_tuple = tuple(sublist)
    if the_tuple not in unique_set:
        unique_set.add(the_tuple)
        result.append(sublist)
```

So all operations on the set are done with tuples. This gives:

```
>>> result
[[1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2], [1, 1, 2], [2, 2, 2]]
```

Comment: Well I am still not getting the desired result :/
I got the below result :
for i in my_list:
...     the_tuple=tuple(i)
...     if the_tuple not in unique_set:
...         unique_set.add(the_tuple)
...         result.append(i)
...         
>>> unique_set
set([((),),
     ((1,), (2,), (2,)),
     ((1, 2), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2))])
>>> result
[[(1,), (2,), (2,)], [(1, 2), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]]
>>>

Comment: @deb: mind that `my_list` contains **all lists**.

Comment: what i mean is it is still showing duplicate lists in the same

Comment: @deb: if you run the code last code fragment (which is self-containig), you get the reported `result`...  You probably have a `for` too much since your unique set seems to construct single element tuples, two-element tuples, etc.

Comment: do you mean apply this to each tuple? that is first to the_tuple[0]and so on..?

Comment: @deb: your question is "filtering out duplicates". The code fragment below shows you how to get a `result` without duplicates. Why do you modify it?

Comment: got your point(y) , was lil silly of me... :D,,, btw thanks @Willem

Answer (score 2):

Lists are not hashable, but you can have a set of tuples, :

```
set(map(tuple, my_list))
# {(1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2)}
```

Comment: This is still showing me all duplicate values